# Find ids in sets of ids in a string - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have column **likes** where i store ids in a in comma separated string: **76,88**

I want to select row from another table whose id is in **78,88**

I tried using MYSQL **IN()** function but it only get first id **78**

so how do i solve it in the same query string?

```
SELECT  u.user_id,
        u.username,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname,u.status

        FROM users u WHERE u.user_id IN(
            SELECT likes FROM posts WHERE post_id='200'
        )
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**FIND_IN_SET()** function returns the position of a string within second string. Returns zero when search string doesn’t exist in string list.

SYNTAX:

**FIND_IN_SET(argument1,argument2)**

SQL will look like this:

```
SELECT  u.user_id,
        u.username,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname,u.status

        FROM users u WHERE FIND_IN_SET(u.user_id,
            (SELECT likes FROM posts WHERE post_id='200') 
        )
```

**Note:** argument1 is a string to check against comma separated string in argument2